# Создание нескольких переменных одной строчкой

Tags: c#

Поясните, пожалуйста, почему не работает создание нескольких переменных таким образом:

```
public class Point
{
    int a;
    int b;
}

Point a, b, c = new Point();
```

??

Comment: Наверное, потому что нужно попробовать так?
Point a = new Point(), b = new Point(), c = new Point();

Comment: тоесть получалось что у меня создаваля только обьект C, а обьекты a и b не учитывались компилятором?

Comment: Думаю, что мыслите в правильном направлении. Но я не спец по C#, поэтому лучше попробуйте и расскажите, что получилось :-)

Comment: Попробывал, и получилось так как описал(создавалась только последняя переменная). Спасибо за подсказку)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что new(оператор захвата памяти), вы используете только для одного обьекта, а захватить одну и ту же память для разных обьектов как это делаете вы - нельзя!